# In Eclipse, Is there a way to disable a breakpoint temporarily?

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints

I have a number of breakpoints scattered throughout my code. I don't want to lose them, I just want to temporarily turn them all off so that the breakpoint I just added is the only one that is triggered. In other words, to have "active" and "inactive" breakpoints. Is this possible in Eclipse? I'm running Neon, 4.6.3.

Answer (score 4):

In the run menu, about halfway down - there's "Skip All Break Points" - or you can do `CTRL+ALT+B`

Just **don't** forget to toggle it back else you'll be wondering why none of your breakpoints are no longer working - been there, done that.

Note and update as you wanted to only disable specific breakpoints, but still have some or a new one enabled.  Too accomplish this:
Window->Show View->Debug Tree Node Select "Breakpoints" - this opens a view with all of your breakpoints.  Select all of them, select disable - now select just the one (or two) that you want!

Comment: Doesn't this turn off *all* breakpoints? I want to disable only some of them, or all but one. I want to have both active and inactive breakpoints at the same time, and only the active ones to be triggered.

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that I misread the "turn them all off so that the breakpoint I just added is the only one" - IMHO - I dont think it's possible but hopefully someone can chime in - ooh, found it, updating answer!

Comment: Glad @nitind and I could help out. Have a great weekend!

Comment: Sorry I haven't accepted an answer yet - I will once I get an opportunity to try them out.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean **Java** breakpoints, yes, you can just right-click on them either in the **Java Editor** or in the **Breakpoints View** and turn them on and off at will. Support in other languages is dependent on the language.

http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/breakpoints/ref-enabled_option.htm?cp=1_4_0_1